# MySQL choose a random row from two joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I know there are simmilar questions out there, but here`s my implementation on a fast random select row:

```
SELECT i.id, i.thumb_img, i.af, i.width, i.height
FROM images_detail id
JOIN images AS i ON id.imageid = i.id
WHERE id.imageid >=1
AND id.newsroom =1
AND i.width > i.height
AND id.imageid >= FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *23111593 )
LIMIT 1
```

The problem with this query is that indifferent of the RANDOM expression in `id.imageid >= FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *23111593 )` it always returns the same ID, why?
Any help please?

Later edit:

The query takes 0.0005 seconds, using `EXPLAIN`, it reports back `USING WHERE` and `12993 ROWS` returned

The Id's are auto-incremented, it's not 23111593 because RAND() returns 0.xxxxx so RAND()*23111593, returns about 12993 rows. The problem is, the same ID is at the top and I don`t want to call an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: How many results are returned if you take off the limit and the RAND section of the where clause?

Comment: @malonso I`ve edited my post to include further details. Thanks!

Comment: What about the distribution of imageid's? Maybe all of the images have ids > 23111593?

Comment: @bububaba The Id`s are auto-incremented, it`s not 23111593 because RAND() returns 0.xxxxx so RAND()*23111593, returns about 12993 rows. The problem is, the same ID is at the top and I don`t want to call an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.greggdev.com/web/articles.php?id=6

or use

ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;

Comment: very slow, especially regarding seveal millions of rows :P using EXPLAIN it states USING TEMPORARY, USING FILESORT...BAD

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any "imageid" in your database that is greater than the span you define (1<=X<=23111593)?

You might have only one entry in the DB.

(also, keep in mind that you might only have one that actually fits the query of id.newsroom = 1, i.width>i.height etc.)

Comment: there are 12000 that fit the WHERE conditions above

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I've loaded ALL the results in an array, stored it in a cache and made in PHP `$key=rand(0,sizeof(array))` and then used it as follows `array[$key]['property']`